# Reporting number of NAs in Bar Plot using ggplot and r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, na

## Goal

I am attempting to create a series of bar plots that display satisfaction with a recent election in 6 countries. The data include NAs, and I want to report the number of NAs for each country in its respective bar plot.

Is there a way to have ggplot / R automatically insert the number of `NA` values in the bar plots? I cannot seem to figure this out on my own. I have put in place-holder text in each graph: `"NA = ##"`.

Thank you!

## Data Structure

The data look like this:

```
Country     Satisfaction
-------     ------------
Algeria     1
Algeria     3
Algeria     NA
...
Burundi     3
Burundi     2
Burundi     2
...
Cameroon    4
Cameroon    NA
Cameroon    NA
...
```

## Example Code

```
countries <- c("Algeria", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon")
countryvar <- rep(countries, each = 30)
satisfaction <- sample(1:5, 180, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.35, 0.1, 0.05))
satisfaction[satisfaction==5] <- NA
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(countryvar, satisfaction))

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = subset(df, !is.na(satisfaction)), aes(satisfaction))
p + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = satisfaction)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ countryvar, nrow = 2) + 
  labs(x = "Satisfaction with Recent Election", y = "Counts") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3.5, xmax = 4.5, ymin = 22.5, ymax = 25, fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  annotate("text", x = 3.6, y = 23.1, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, label = "NA = ##") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("snow3", "seashell3", "snow4", "black"))  +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `geom_text`.

Basically count the `NA` per country

```
subset(df, is.na(satisfaction))%>%
                 count(countryvar)
```

and use that as data for `geom_text`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = subset(df, !is.na(satisfaction)), aes(satisfaction))
p + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = satisfaction)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ countryvar, nrow = 2) + 
  labs(x = "Satisfaction with Recent Election", y = "Counts") + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3.5, xmax = 4.5, ymin = 22.5, ymax = 25, fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  geom_text(data = subset(df, is.na(satisfaction))%>%
             count(countryvar), x = 3.6, y = 23.1, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, aes(label = paste("NA = ", n))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("snow3", "seashell3", "snow4", "black"))  +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]